# Where to open file in a Perl module

Tags: perl, module, file-handling

Below is a toy version of a module I'm writing. This example faithfully demonstrates the problem I having.

I have a file `bed_in.txt`

```
2L      0       4953
2L      16204   16284
2L      16612   16805
2L      17086   18561
2L      18757   18758
2L      19040   19120
2L      19445   19635
2L      19894   21366
2L      21582   21583
2L      47501   52365
2L      4698700 4709369
```

that I want to use to filter values in an array.

I want to check whether the second column of `bed_in.txt` matches any value in

```
my @lines = qw/ 16204 40 200 149 19445 178 /;
```

push *this* to an array if so.

My final output for this data should be the two elements in `@lines` that are also in the second column of `bed_in.txt`

```
2L      0       4953
2L      16204   16284 # 16204 == 16204
2L      16612   16805
2L      17086   18561
2L      18757   18758
2L      19040   19120
2L      19445   19635 # 19445 == 19445
```

But where should I open my file?

Should this happen in the script that calls my module `run_fileOpen.pl`, or in the module itself?

In either case, I am not getting the correct output, and my module appears to be called for only the first element of `@lines`

#### parseFile.pm

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

package parseFile;
use strict;
use warnings;

use FindBin qw/ $Bin /;
use lib File::Spec->catdir($FindBin::Bin, '..', 'bin/');

use Data::Printer;

open my $bed, '<', 'bed_in.txt';

sub check_lines {
  my ($line, $filter_ref) = @_;
  my @filter_reasons = @{ $filter_ref };

  my $lines_to_filter_ref = filter_lines($line, $bed, \@filter_reasons);

  return($lines_to_filter_ref);
}


sub filter_lines {
  my ($line, $bed_file, $lines_to_filter) = @_;

  my @filter = @{ $lines_to_filter };

  while(<$bed_file>){
    chomp;
    my $start = (split)[1];
    # print "line: $line  start: $start\n";
    if ($line == $start ) {

      push @filter, "Filter as equal: $start, $line [$_]";
    }
  }
  # p(@filter);
  return(\@filter);
}


1;
```

#### run_parseFile.pl

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use parseFile;


my @lines = qw/ 16204 40 200 149 19445 178 /;

foreach(@lines){
  my @filter_reasons = 'reason 1';
  my $lines2filter = parseFile::check_lines($_, \@filter_reasons);
  @filter_reasons = @{ $lines2filter };
  print "$_\n" foreach @filter_reasons;
}
```

#### Output

```
reason 1
Filter as equal: 16204, 16204 [2L   16204   16284]
reason 1
reason 1
reason 1
reason 1
reason 1
```

When I add a `print` statement to the `while` loop in `filter_lines` I can see that only the first element is being run:

```
line: 16204  start: 0
line: 16204  start: 16204
line: 16204  start: 16612
line: 16204  start: 17086
line: 16204  start: 18757
line: 16204  start: 19040
line: 16204  start: 19445
line: 16204  start: 19894
line: 16204  start: 21582
line: 16204  start: 47501
line: 16204  start: 4698700
```

Is this an appropriate way to deal with opening my `bed_in.txt` file, or should I open it in the `run_parseFile.pl` script? Or is there something else entirely wrong with my code?

Comment: How big is `bed_in.txt` in reality?

Comment: A module should usually not open a file with a static path, that's why it's called module. It's supposed to be usable in different contexts.Additionally it should not open a file in the body (at compile time), but only when a method/subroutine is called. Otherwise it's not quite testable.

Comment: @Borodin 21154 lines

Comment: The reason you are seeing only one value checked is because the first call to `filter_lines` reads the file to the end. Subsequent calls find the file handle at eof so there is nothing to read and the `while` is never executed again. You could open the file in `filter_lines` to fix that, but if there are always multiple values to be tested then that's very inefficient. I'd be inclined to make this an object-oriented module anyway.

Comment: What is your required output for this code? Is the `Filter as equal` output just debugging code?

Comment: @Borodin Aha! OK, that's obviously the reason then. I'm a little confused as to why the while statement's not executed for each line

Comment: @Borodin The expected output for element 1 of `@lines` is an array with `['reason 1', 'Filter as equal: 16204, 16204 [2L   16204   16284]']`. All other lines should return an array with `['reason 1']` except the second line I highlight as matching, which should return: `['reason 1', 'Filter as equal: 19445, 19445 [2L      19445   19635]']`

Comment: @Borodin - I then filter all `@lines` where  `scalar @{$filter_reasons} != 0`

Comment: Is there a reason for `@filter_reasons` being an array? Can you filter for multiple reasons at once? What should the result be in that case?

Comment: @Borodin - not strictly speaking, no. It allows me to inspect why a particular element is being filtered. I use this approach throughout my module, which except for this function, works as intended (although almost certainly not optimised for efficiency/memory)

Comment: Presumably you mean `@$lines2filter > 1`? They will always contain at least the reason code.

Comment: @Borodin yes sorry - in this example that's the case

Comment: I don't see why using a simple scalar value prevents you from inspecting why an element is being filtered.

Comment: @fugu: *"in this example that's the case"* This worries me. Your use of `\@filter_reasons` and `return(\@filter)` when both arrays have only a single element is significant, and it's hard to be sure that an answer is useful when you're clearly withholding details. Your answer that a match *"should return: `['reason 1', 'Filter as equal: 19445, 19445 [2L 19445 19635]']`"* doesn't come close to what your code actually does.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would write this. As I said, I prefer an object-oriented solution

The `new` constructor requires a file name as its parameter. It opens the file, reads the information into a hash, and blesses to make the object

The only method is `check_lines`, which expects a value and a reason string. It simply interrogates the hash for the given value and returns a one- or two-element array according to whether the value was found

It is best to limit the scope of this object as otherwise the hash will be kept in memory after it is required. So I've enclosed all the operations that require the object in a block. The object will be automatically destroyed when it goes out of scope at the end of the block

#### BedInFilter.pm

```perl
package BedInFilter;

use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Carp 'croak';

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my ( $bed_file ) = @_;

    my %self;

    open my $fh, '<', $bed_file
            or croak qq{Unable to open "$bed_file" for input: $!};

    while ( <$fh> ) {

        next unless /\S/;
        chomp;

        my $val = ( split )[1];
        $self{$val} = $_;
    }

    bless \%self, $class;
}

sub check_lines {
    my $self = shift;
    my ( $val, $reason ) = @_;

    my $result = [ $reason ];

    my $line = $self->{$val};

    push @$result, "Filter as equal: $val, $val [$line]" if $line;

    $result;
}

1;
```

#### bed_in.pl

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use BedInFilter;

my @values = qw/ 16204 40 200 149 19445 178 /;

{
    my $filter = BedInFilter->new( 'bed_in.txt' );

    for my $val ( @values ) {

        my $reason = 'reason1';

        my $result = $filter->check_lines( $val, $reason );

        print "@$result\n";
    }
}
```

#### output

```
reason1 Filter as equal: 16204, 16204 [2L      16204   16284]
reason1
reason1
reason1
reason1 Filter as equal: 19445, 19445 [2L      19445   19635]
reason1
```

Answer (score 0):

A module should open and close files in the same subroutine unless the name of the sub has "open" in it, in which case, it should return a file handle as one of its return values. And there should be a corresponding "close" sub to match every "open" sub.